# mido + python-rtmidi get_compiled_api() returning "web", no MIDI port detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, midi, mido

I'm currently working on a script to convert MIDI inputs to Virtual Keyboard-style QWERTY outputs. The script I had was correctly working several months ago, but as of now is inexplicably failing to find any of my MIDI inputs.

I'm using the `keyboard`, `mido`, and `mido.backends.rtmidi` modules to do this. `mido.backends.rtmidi` runs off of `python_rtmidi`.

I've spent a while debugging and researching, finding that `mido.backends.rtmidi.get_devices()` returns an empty list (`[]`), rather than the MIDI keyboard and loopMIDI virtual input I have set up. Both of these inputs are detectable by typical DAWs such as FL Studio and Ableton Live.
Researching the APIs further gives me the `rtmidi.get_compiled_api()` method, which using the below code returns `web` and `Web MIDI API`. According to the [documentation](https://spotlightkid.github.io/python-rtmidi/rtmidi.html#functions), this should return a string such as `API_WINDOWS_MM` or `Windows Multimedia MIDI API`.

The code in question:

```py
for api in rtmidi.get_compiled_api():
    print(rtmidi.get_api_name(api)) #outputs "web"
    print(rtmidi.get_api_display_name(api)) #outputs "Web MIDI API"
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I get it to detect the inputs of my MIDI devices?